# Ant: Why are my CLI args not persisting when I invoke targets that use them?

Tags: ant

I have a property and target in my `build.xml`:

```
<property name="somedir" value="path/to/dir/${prop}"/>
<echo message="${prop}"/>

<target name="foo">
  <echo message="Property:  ${somedir}"/>
</target>
```

In the directory where `build.xml` is I run:

```
ant -Dprop="someVal" foo
```

This gets echoed:

```
[echo] someVal
[echo] Property:  path/to/dir/
```

What happened to `${prop}` when `foo` is called? How do I get the value to persist when `foo` is invoked?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your issue. What version of ANT are you using?

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="foo">
  <property name="somedir" value="path/to/dir/${prop}"/>
  <echo message="${prop}"/>
  <target name="foo">
    <echo message="Property:  ${somedir}"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

Run as follows:

```
$ ant -Dprop=hello
Buildfile: /home/me/tmp/build.xml
     [echo] hello

foo:
     [echo] Property:  path/to/dir/hello
```

ANT version:

```
$ ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.0 compiled on March 5 2013
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ant version 1.8.4

I have this as my `build.xml`

```
<project>
    <property name="somedir" value="path/to/dir/${prop}"/>
    <echo message="${prop}"/>

    <target name="foo">
        <echo message="Property:  ${somedir}"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

I get this:

```
$ ant -Dprop=foo foo
Buildfile: /Users/david/build.xml
     [echo] foo

foo:
     [echo] Property:  path/to/dir/foo

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

I had to put `<project>` and `</project>` in the build.xml or else it wouldn't execute.

Is there something I'm missing? It seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to overwrite a pre-defined property that is immutable from the `build.xml` ...this is more along the lines of what I'm trying to do:

```
  <project>
    <property name="basedir" value="/usr/me/${prop}"/>
    <echo message="${basedir}"/>
  </project>
```

echos:

```
Buildfile: build.xml

     [echo] /usr/me

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

**facepalm**